# Is moving a potted plant with vegetables from the ground to a table change its status as far as Shmita?

Tags: halacha, agriculture, shmita

If potted vegetables on the ground (considered shmita worthy) is placed on a table, does this change its status as far as the laws concerning shmita food?

Comment: Does tge pot have a hole in the bottom?

Comment: @DoubleAA It has holes on the bottom but it sits on a plate. But  what about if it had holes and sat on the floor of a balcony ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the vegetables have grown (somewhat) during Shmita, then even moving them to a *non-Shmita* location, would not remove the Shmita status.

**If part of the vegie is Shmita, the entire vegie is Shmita.**

Source: Mishna in [Shvi'is 6:3](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01078.html#HtmpReportNum0049_L2). Relevant parts of the Bartenura:

> בְּצָלִים שֶׁל שִׁשִּׁית שֶׁנִּכְנְסוּ לַשְּׁבִיעִית, וְיָרְדוּ עֲלֵיהֶם גְּשָׁמִים וְצָמְחוּ, אִם הִשְׁחִירוּ הֶעָלִין בְּיָדוּעַ שֶׁגָּדְלוּ וְהוֹסִיפוּ, **וַאֲתוּ גִּדּוּלֵי שְׁבִיעִית וּמְבַטְּלִים הָעִקָּר אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהוּא מְרֻבֶּה**.‏

The Rambam in [הלכות שמיטה ויובל in Ch. 4:20](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02022.html#HtmpReportNum0075_L2) paskens like this Mishna.